# Joomla 3.2.3 has email sending bug I believe - Is it true?

Tags: email, joomla

I used few email sending third party modules... and every time same problem happened..

problem: 
I sign in as any user at my front-end and send a email - Email is successfully mailed & I receive mail in my mail box
But if i do the same thing without any user being logged in ... as a visitor then on submit that form is displayed again with blank fields + No errors Reports and no mail is send & received...

normally in other versions of joomla those same forms either show a error saying Mail Not Send ..or Could not Instiate etc ...  & If they successfully send it - those form show a Thank You msg

Modules I used - 
1.Rapid Contact &
2.Responsive Contact Form

Now I shifted to another Joomla version & both are working perfectly....

Please help

Comment: Could possibly be a bug with those specific modules, not entirely sure. Might be best contacting the developer of each one to ask

Comment: I contacted on of the developer but no - reply, But i want you to notice on the point that this modules are working fine in other version like 2.5, 3.2.0 etc ... not jus in 3.2.3 - why so ... Either was a problem in some access rights in my site or something else was creating a problem ...